Does "any computer(s) you have" refer to one or all the computers?

Give me any computer you have in your house.

Give me any computers you have in your house.


Am I asking for one of the computers in your house or all of them or...?


I did all I could to convince him to give me any computer in his house.

I did all I could to convince him to give me any computers in his house.


Did I try to convince him to give me one of the computers in his house or all of them?
A similar question had been asked, but it was about conditional sentences. These sentences are not conditional.
In another case, the sentences were interrogative. Again, not exactly the same thing.

This has been asked before, see here and here

This question is similar to: Singular or plural nouns after "if any". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Give me any computer you have in your house.

Is asking for one computer and doesn't specify which, so they could give you the old broken one in the back of the cupboard.

Give me any computers you have in your house.

Is asking for all the computers in the house, including the one in the cupboard. But it would be clearer to say

Give me all the computers you have in your house.

By the same reasoning (3) you asked for one computer (4) you asked for all of them.

Why bring "the garage" into it? That seems like it might confuse the OP by giving the impression that we're distinguishing between what counts as "in the house" or not.

@AndyBonner OK, I've changed garage to cupboard.

And why cupboard? There was no cupboard mentioned in the question? Do you maybe mean "also those which are not apparently visible"? Maybe the probably intended wink is more confusing than helpful. Otherwise, a concise answer! (+1)

I'd say the difference between "any computers you have in your house" and "all the computers you have in your house" is that the latter carries more of an assumption that there are computers in the house, whereas for the former the speaker may not even think it likely that there are any. Consider the example of a security guard at a concert saying "give me any weapons that you have on you". He doesn't expect that you have weapons, he just says in case you do you should hand them in.

One case lefts unstudied in this answer is "any of the [plural]", which is notably different from "any [plural]". The latter means "all", but the former allows a subset of the total.

I think all the sentences are formally ambiguous.  The specific meaning depends on the larger context.  Out of context, I think most English speakers would avoid these sentences or add heavy intonation to try to clarify the meaning.  With heavy stress just on the word "any," the meaning would tend to be what I describe in B. below.
I can think of three common meanings of "any," all of which include some notion of indifference:
A.  "Any" is the same as "all" except that "all" implies that the contemplated set of things has members in it; whereas "any" explicitly allows that the contemplated set has no members.  You use this when you are indifferent to whether the set has members or not (i.e., "any members").

E.g., Give me all the change you have.  I want to make sure we will
have enough coins to pay the parking meters.  (I say this because I
believe you have some change.)
Give me any change you have.  I want to see if we'll have enough for
coffee. (I say this because I am explicitly allowing for the fact that
you may have no change at all, and my need is indifferent to whether or not you have (any) change.)

B. "Any" refers to one or more members of a given set of things and asserts
that which member or members are selected is unimportant.

E.g., Any book you give me will do.  I just want something to weigh
down this piece of paper.  (I am indifferent as to which book you give me.)

C. "Any" is the typical equivalent of "some" in interrogative and negative sentences, retaining some of its other connotations.

E.g., I don't have any change or any books.  Don't you have any?  (Since I have neither change nor books, I am indifferent as to which ones they theoretically could be.  In asking you, I am indifferent as to what example you might name.)

Addressing the numbered questions in the original post:

Compare:


a. Give me any computer you have in your house.  I don't care how old or
how small.  Any of them might have a virus to allow someone to listen
in on our conversations.  (Here, I want all the computers since I am indifferent as to their number.)(Since it is common for households to have more than one computer, this sentence would be more common in the plural.)
b. Give me any computer you have in your house.  I just need one to do
some quick calculations I can't do on the tiny keys on my cellphone
without cramping up.  (Here, I want only one computer and am
indifferent as to which one.)


Making "computer" plural yields the same ambiguities as in (1).

Compare:



a. I did all I could to convince him to give me any computer in his
house. Now that our new alien overlords have outlawed possession of
computers, keeping any and all computers could result in arrest.  (The law applies and is indifferent to how many computers you have.)(Again, it would be more common to say "computers" in the plural.)
b. I did all I could to convince him to give me any computer in his
house.  He has a ton of them, and I thought he would be willing to
spare me at least one of the old ones.  (I am indifferent as to which computer I am given.)


Again, making "computers" plural yields the same ambiguities.

You could help disambiguate these sentences in various ways.  E.g.:

Give me any and all computers in your house. (I want all of them.)
Just give me any computer in your house at all.  (I don't care which
one.)
I did all I could to convince him to give me any computers he might
have in his house.  (I want all.)
I did all I could to convince him to give my any one of the computers
in his house.  (I don't care which one.)


A long answer to a Yes/No question. But might be helpful (+1)

"Making "computer" plural yields the same ambiguities as in (1)" I disagree here. "Any [singular]" is not the same as "any [plural]". However, I do agree that "any [singular]" is the same as "any of the [plural]". The key point here is that "any of the [plural]" (= subset of what exists) is different from "any [plural]" (= all that exist, but unspecified if they exist in the first place). I.e. "Give me any compliment you can think of" is the same as "Give me any of the compliments you can think of", but not the same as "Give me any compliments you can think of" (which means "all").
